# How to generate Outlook email with info from Excel table?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to loop through a table on any sheet across a workbook and generate emails with info from that table to the individuals on each line.

`.Body` is no longer sending information to Outlook.

Shorter test messages worked but now it isn't sending any body text to Outlook. My `.To` line is working as is `.Subject`.

```vb
With OutMail
    .To = Range("D" & i).Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ActiveSheet.Name & " Service Insert"
    '.HTMLBody = "Hi " & Range(C, i).Value & "<br><br>" & "Please see your Service Insert Below." & "<br>" & "<br>" _
    & Range(S, 1).Value & "<br>" & "Services Played: " & Range(S, i).Value & "<br>" & "Doubling Services: " & Range("T" & i).Value & "<br>" & "Move Up Services: " & Range("W" & i).Value & " services from " & Range(Y, i) & "<br>" & "Solo Services: " & Range(Z, i).Value & "<br><br>" _
    & Range(AA, 1).Value & "<br>" & "Services Played: " & Range(AA, i).Value & "<br>" & "Doubling Services: " & Range(AB, i).Value & "<br>" & "Move Up Services: " & Range(AE, i).Value & " services from " & Range(AG, i) & "<br>" & "Solo Services: " & Range(AH, i).Value & "<br><br>" _
    & "Pay Period Totals" & "<br>" & "Total Leave Used: " & Range(F, i).Value & "<br>" & "Sick Leave Used: " & Range(i, i).Value & "<br>" & "Total Doubling Pay: " & Range(K, i).Value & "<br>" & "Total Move Up Pay: " & Range(L, i).Value & "<br>" & "Total Solo Pay: " & Range(M, i).Value & "<br>" & "Total Pay Correction: " & Range(N, i).Value & "<br>" & "Parking Reimbursement: " & Range(O, i).Value & "<br>" & "Mileage Reimbursement: " & Range(P, i).Value & "<br>" & "Travel Reimbursement: " & Range(Q, i).Value & "<br>" & "Total Additional Pay: " & Range(R, i).Value & "<br><br>" _
    & "Season Totals" & "<br><br>" & "Total Season Services Used: " & Range(AZ, i).Value & "<br>" & "Sick Leave Remaining: " & Range(AY, i).Value & "<br><br>" & "Please let me know if you have any questions or concerns." & "<br><br>" & "Best, "
    
    .Body = "Hi " & Range("C" & i).Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please see your Service Insert Below." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & Range("S1").Value & vbNewLine & "Services Played: " & Range("S" & i).Value & vbNewLine & "Doubling Services: " & Range("T" & i).Value & vbNewLine & "Move Up Services: " & Range("W" & i).Value & " services from " & Range("Y" & i) & vbNewLine & "Solo Services: " & Range("Z" & i).Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & Range("AA1").Value & vbNewLine & "Services Played: " & Range("AA" & i).Value & vbNewLine & "Doubling Services: " & Range("AB" & i).Value & vbNewLine & "Move Up Services: " & Range("AE" & i).Value & " services from " & Range("AG" & i) & vbNewLine & "Solo Services: " & Range("AH" & i).Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & "Pay Period Totals" & vbNewLine & "Total Leave Used: " & Range("F" & i).Value & vbNewLine & "Sick Leave Used: " & Range("I" & i).Value & vbNewLine & "Total Doubling Pay: " & Range("K" And i).Value & vbNewLine & "Total Move Up Pay: " & Range("L" And i).Value & vbNewLine & "Total Solo Pay: " & Range("M" And i).Value & vbNewLine & "Total Pay Correction: " & Range("N" And i).Value & vbNewLine & "Parking Reimbursement: " & Range("O" And i).Value & vbNewLine & "Mileage Reimbursement: " & Range("P" And i).Value & vbNewLine & "Travel Reimbursement: " & Range("Q" And i).Value & vbNewLine & "Total Additional Pay: " & Range("R" And i).Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & "Season Totals" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Total Season Services Used: " & Range("AZ" & i).Value & vbNewLine & "Sick Leave Remaining: " & Range("AY" & i).Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please let me know if you have any questions or concerns." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Best, "
    
    '.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Display   'or use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
```

Above is the code with `.Body` and `.HTMLBody` that I tried. Neither is sending any information to Outlook.

---

After commenting out `On Error Resume Next` above posted code, I get

> Type mismatch error

on the body text. It stayed when I tried to define it independently as a string and use the string for the body.

Comment: Looks like you may have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere above your posted code.  What happens if you comment that out?  FYI `Range(C, i)` should be `Range("C" & i)` or maybe `Cells(i, "C")`

Comment: If you put `Option Explicit` at the top of that module, it will catch all the mistakes you made in using undeclared variables. Keep in mind that when using 2 arguments in your range, the `Row` comes first, and the `Column` comes second. You have it the other way around.

Comment: After commenting our On Error Resume Next I'm getting a Type mismatch error on the body text. It stayed when I tried to define it independently as a string and call the string to the body.

Comment: _After commenting our On Error Resume Next I'm getting a Type mismatch_ well, there's your issue - `On Error Resume Next` didn't fixed your problem, it just hid it from you

Comment: Your problem isn't with `.Body`, it's how your are building your string.  Burried in that awful long string concatination are a number of range references like `Range("L" And i)`.  These return a Type Mismatch.  they should be like `Range("L" & i)`

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable to create your body string by making some concatenations then assign the string to `.Body`. This way you can easily check your string and find an error by running step by step.

```
Dim emailBody as string: emailBody = ""

emailBody = emailBody & "Hi " & Range("C" & i).Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
emailBody = emailBody & "Please see your Service Insert Below." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
emailBody = emailBody & Range("S1").Value & vbNewLine
...

With OutMail
    ...
    .Body = emailBody
    ...
End With
```